# Get realtime Facebook profile notifications / post comments Node.js

Tags: node.js, facebook

I want to create a bot using Node.js that gets notifications from my Facebook profile and if someone commented one of my posts then the bot will reply to them.

Is there a way I can get those notifications or post comments in realtime ?

Comment: No there is no way to access notifications using the API.

Comment: You could in the past access pretty much any information or content of the user, but FB has since deprecated the access due privacy issues(see the Cambridge Analytical scandal).

Comment: That is possible for pages, but not user profiles.